# JAXB marshals "non-field"

Tags: java, jaxb, xmltransient

I have a class called Ability that inherits from an abstract class `CampaignObject`.

`CampaignObject` has an abstract method called `getInfo()`.

Abilities do not have their own Info. If they are asked for info, the info of their Owner should be provided.

When I use `JAXB.marshal(...)` to marshal that, it includes the owners info text as an `XmlElement` on every ability. Annotating `Ability.getInfo()` with `@XmlTransient` does not make a difference.

What can I do?

Thanks a lot.

Code like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ability")
public class Ability extends CampaignObject {


    private String val;
    private Hero owner;

    ...

    @Override
    @XmlTransient
    public String getInfo() {
       return getOwner().getInfo();
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Hero getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` to your class to be sure it doesn"t use anything besides what you annotated for the mapping, this way, you should also be able to remove the `@XmlTransient` annotations.

Comment: Didn't help. Neither did the opposite: `XmlAccessType.FIELD`

Comment: Changed the answer to another idea i had.

Answer (score 0):

I have circumvented the problem. I refactored/renamed `getInfo()` into `retrieveInfo()` and gave everything except Abilities a new `getInfo()`.

Still, if anyone has an idea on how to actually solve the issue, I'm still willing to learn.